# I am trying to take the 95th quantile of each group of records in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, quantile

I am trying to get the 95th quantile for each group of rows in a dataframe.  I have tried:
mdf=mdf.groupby('GroupID').quantile(.95)

but the interpreter returns an error:
ValueError: 'GroupID' is both an index level and a column label, which is ambiguous.

I have three columns and I want the 95th of Utilization for each group:
GroupID, Timestamp, Util

Code below:

```
#pandas 95th percentile calculator

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 8)

cfile = "path"
rfile = "path"

#define columns in corereport dataframe
cdf = pd.read_csv(cfile, skiprows = 1, names = ['ID','Device','Bundle','IsPolled','Status','SpeedIn','SpeedOut','Timestamp','MaxIn','MaxOut'])

#drop specified columns from dataframe
to_drop = ['Device', 'Bundle', 'IsPolled', 'Status', 'SpeedIn', 'SpeedOut']
cdf.drop(to_drop, inplace=True, axis=1)

#define columns in relationship dataframe
rdf = pd.read_csv(rfile, skiprows = 1, names = ['GroupID', 'ID', 'Path', 'LowestBW', 'TotalBW'])

#merge the two dataframes together on the ID field
mdf = pd.merge(cdf, rdf, left_on='ID', right_on='ID', how = 'left')

#print(mdf.head())

#Add a column with the larger of two values of MaxIn and MaxOut for each row
mdf.loc[mdf['MaxIn'] > mdf['MaxOut'], 'Util'] = mdf['MaxIn']
mdf.loc[mdf['MaxIn'] < mdf['MaxOut'], 'Util'] = mdf['MaxOut']

#drop specified columns from data frame
to_drop = ['ID', 'MaxIn', 'MaxOut', 'Path', 'LowestBW', 'TotalBW']
mdf.drop(to_drop, inplace=True, axis=1)

#print(mdf.head().values)

#Group by the GroupID and Timestamp Columns and sum the value in Util
mdf = mdf.groupby(['GroupID', 'Timestamp'])['Util'].sum().reset_index()

#Grouping by GroupID and then sorting ascending
mdf = mdf.groupby(['GroupID']).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(['Util']))

mdf = mdf.groupby('GroupID').quantile(.95)

#Write new dataframe out to a csv
ofile = 'path'
mdf.to_csv(ofile, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
mdf = mdf.groupby(['GroupID']).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(['Util']))
```

which sets `'GroupID'` as index of `mdf`. Try instead:

```
mdf = (mdf.groupby(['GroupID'])[['Timestamp', 'Util']]
       .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(['Util'])))
```

or

```
mdf.sort_values(['GroupID', 'Util'], inplace=True)
```

However, I believe you don't need to sort values for `quantile`.

Comment: You are absolutely correct that removing the .apply line of code both solved my error and still allowed quantile to compute the correct number. Thank you for the help!